# How to switch between two php scripts

Tags: php, mysql

currently I'm working on a project that fills up a main-database.

Right now it consists of two scripts and a source-database.

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Script 1 connects to source-db, grabs a city and passes the city as a session-variable via `header('Location Script2.php')` to Script 2.
2. Script 2 does a lot of work then (collecting specific data, stores in Array) and saves it in the main-database.

That works fine so far.

3. Script 2 shall now start Script 1 again, to fetch the next city in the db.

That's where I'm stuck (I tried all solutions I could find on here):

- again via Header
- CURL
- shell_exec
- etc.

So far, nothing worked.

Any suggestions, ideas or input are very much appreciated!

Many thanks in advance and I look forward to learn from any knowledgeable person on here!

Great evening to you all

Here's the code:

**Script 1:**
Grab the first city with Status "1" (when finished "Status" is updated to "0"):

```
$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname)
or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());


// Wählt immer die erste Zeile mit Status "0" aus
$query = "SELECT City FROM citydb WHERE Status = '1' LIMIT 1";

//Packt Stadtname in $location
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($field1);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $loc = $field1;
    }
    $stmt->close();
}

// Überträgt die Variable $location
if ( empty($loc) !== FALSE){
    echo "Nichts mehr da!";
    exit;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['$location'] = $loc;
        header('Location: xxxxxxx/xxxx-get-basicdata.php');
        exit;
    }
```

**Script 2:**
Processing, saving, restart

```
$dbkeys = "(" . implode(", ", array_keys($details)) . ")";
$dbvalues = "('" . implode("', '", $details) . "')";
$query = "INSERT INTO data " . $dbkeys . " VALUES " . $dbvalues;

// // UPDATING STATUS IN CITIES-DB
$query = "UPDATE citydb SET STATUS = 0 WHERE City = ('$city')";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
/////////// THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK
/////////// here script 1 should be called (at least I thought so)
} else{
echo "ERROR: Not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
exit;
}
```

PS: Just for the case the same question came up before or else: I'd be happy if someone could just give me a hint/link. I don't want to have a perfect solution, just an idea what to look into.

Comment: This seems like a bad design. The browser will eventually complain about a redirect loop if it keeps going back and forth between the two scripts. Why don't you just use `require()` in the first script so it can call the functions from the second script in a loop?

Comment: Pls note Stackoverflow is a help-with-coding-bug service. But not to figure out how to do things. Kindly refrain asking such questions.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I had in mind first. However, I was thinking that the script will run too long which will eventually crash it. To get an idea: the list of cities is around 12,000 entries and for all of them a separate process is required (to get the data). So unless there is a way to "clear" in between I think this would not work. Maybe I should also say that I just started getting into php like 5 weeks ago, so I guess there's left a lot to learn...

Comment: I agree, I think there are some efficiency issues here. Can you post your code please?

Comment: That might be very well the case. I added the critical snippets in the OP.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: If the script takes too long consider making a background job that kicks off. There's many ways to do this with PHP and modules on [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) to help get started.

Comment: Agree with @tadman. Scripts that run for a long time should be done as batch jobs, not run interactively from the browser. You can use `crontab` to schedule periodic executions.

Comment: @tadman:Thanks. I know, I know, the sql injection issue really is something I need to work on. For now I just wanted to get it going in general. And regarding OOP: I also know that this is the way it should be done and that I probably wrote a lot of crap.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks. I will definitely take a look at that! Much appreciated

Comment: Getting it going broken with tons of SQL injection bugs is not really going at all. That's a pattern you need to avoid because if you accidentally ship code that "works" you expose yourself to huge risks. Additionally, using placeholder values means escaping problems won't exist, you can focus on fixing real bugs instead of hunting down missing quotes. Do it right the first time and you won't have to do it again later. It's honestly easier.

Comment: You may find you'll be more effective when building applications if you to look at various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) first to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and much stronger guidance on how to write your code and organize your files.